# why cant i see prints and logs from lambda in cloudwatch , the function is invoked repeatedly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

lambda backend function is invoked every 20 sec from s3 static website - GET request goes via api gateway calls lambda, it tries to get item from dynamodb table and should return it. It returns 500 error- smth wrong on server side.

- Enough time(9sec) is given for the lambda to finish executing code - lambda's own time out should not be an issue.
- Lambda has a role attached that allows get_item from dynamodb table - IAM is not an issue.

However, when troubleshooting i only see logs in cloudwatch until it tries to get_item. I put lots of print and logs, but it does not go past that line, I even nested try..except - it does not catch any errors. I dont see how to detect whats' wrong. I set logging level to debug - it prints some stuff.

```
import logging
import boto3
import sys

logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    logging.info('doing retrieving from table votes')
    try:
        logging.info('********************* TRYING retrieving from table votes')
        # dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb')
        table = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-east-1').Table('Votes')
        print(table)
        logging.info('event')
        logging.info(event)
        print(type(table))
        logging.info(table)
        logging.info(type(table))
        # logging.error(table)
        # logging.error(type(table))
        


        #************************
        # I dont see the result of count nowhere in the logs of cloud watch
        try:
            count = table.get_item(Key={'voter':{'S': 'count'}})
        except Exception as e:
            logging.info('catching it here - if you see it then something wrong with get_item count')
            logging.info('********************BAD******************')
            logging.error('********************BAD******************')
            e = sys.exc_info()[0]
            exception_type = e.__class__.__name__
            exception_message = str(e)
            logging.error('--------------------------------')
            logging.error(exception_message)
            logging.error(exception_type)
                  
        ##################  BELOW DONT GET PRINTED AT ALL in cloud watch logs
        logging.info('count')
        logging.info(count)
        print('****************COUNT*********************')
        print(count)
        print('----------------------------------------------------')
        logging.info(count)
        a = count["Item"]["a"]
        b = count["Item"]["b"]
        logging.info('count [Item]')
        logging.info(count["Item"])
        logging.info('------------------------------------')
        logging.info('ok retrieve from table votes')
        logging.info('a is ' + a)
        logging.info('b is ' + b)
        logging.info('************************************ success! a: ' + a + ' and b: ' + b)
        return {'statusCode': 200, 'body': '{"a": ' + a + ', "b": ' + b + '}'}  
    
    except Exception as e:
        logging.info('********************BAD******************')
        e = sys.exc_info()[0]
        exception_type = e.__class__.__name__
        exception_message = str(e)
        logging.error('--------------------------------')
        logging.error(exception_message)
        logging.error(exception_type)
        logging.error('---------------------------------------------')
        return {'statusCode': 500, 'body': '{"status": "error getting from table votes"}'}
```

the full logs of 1 request id from start to finish. For some reason it never prints  the result of "count = get_item)

```
START RequestId: 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Version: $LATEST
2023-01-11T21:29:08.805+05:00 
[INFO] 2023-01-11T16:29:08.805Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd doing retrieving from table votes
2023-01-11T21:29:08.805+05:00 
[INFO] 2023-01-11T16:29:08.805Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd ********************* TRYING retrieving from table votes
2023-01-11T21:29:08.806+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:08.806Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Changing event name from creating-client-class.iot-data to creating-client-class.iot-data-plane
2023-01-11T21:29:08.824+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:08.824Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Changing event name from before-call.apigateway to before-call.api-gateway
2023-01-11T21:29:08.825+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:08.825Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Changing event name from request-created.machinelearning.Predict to request-created.machine-learning.Predict
2023-01-11T21:29:08.826+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:08.826Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Changing event name from before-parameter-build.autoscaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration to before-parameter-build.auto-scaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration
2023-01-11T21:29:08.827+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:08.827Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Changing event name from before-parameter-build.route53 to before-parameter-build.route-53
2023-01-11T21:29:08.827+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:08.827Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Changing event name from request-created.cloudsearchdomain.Search to request-created.cloudsearch-domain.Search
2023-01-11T21:29:08.884+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:08.884Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Changing event name from docs.*.autoscaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration.complete-section to docs.*.auto-scaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration.complete-section
2023-01-11T21:29:08.925+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:08.924Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Changing event name from before-parameter-build.logs.CreateExportTask to before-parameter-build.cloudwatch-logs.CreateExportTask
2023-01-11T21:29:08.925+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:08.925Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Changing event name from docs.*.logs.CreateExportTask.complete-section to docs.*.cloudwatch-logs.CreateExportTask.complete-section
2023-01-11T21:29:08.925+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:08.925Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Changing event name from before-parameter-build.cloudsearchdomain.Search to before-parameter-build.cloudsearch-domain.Search
2023-01-11T21:29:08.925+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:08.925Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Changing event name from docs.*.cloudsearchdomain.Search.complete-section to docs.*.cloudsearch-domain.Search.complete-section
2023-01-11T21:29:09.044+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.044Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Loading JSON file: /var/runtime/boto3/data/dynamodb/2012-08-10/resources-1.json
2023-01-11T21:29:09.047+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.047Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd IMDS ENDPOINT: http://169.254.169.254/
2023-01-11T21:29:09.105+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.105Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Looking for credentials via: env
2023-01-11T21:29:09.105+05:00
[INFO] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.105Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Found credentials in environment variables.
2023-01-11T21:29:09.106+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.106Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Loading JSON file: /var/runtime/botocore/data/endpoints.json
2023-01-11T21:29:09.266+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.266Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Event choose-service-name: calling handler <function handle_service_name_alias at 0x7fa39bdec160>
2023-01-11T21:29:09.365+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.364Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Loading JSON file: /var/runtime/botocore/data/dynamodb/2012-08-10/service-2.json
2023-01-11T21:29:09.427+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.426Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Event creating-client-class.dynamodb: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_url at 0x7fa39be91c10>
2023-01-11T21:29:09.485+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.484Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Setting dynamodb timeout as (60, 60)
2023-01-11T21:29:09.485+05:00 
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.485Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Loading JSON file: /var/runtime/botocore/data/_retry.json
2023-01-11T21:29:09.486+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.486Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Registering retry handlers for service: dynamodb
2023-01-11T21:29:09.487+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.486Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Loading dynamodb:dynamodb
2023-01-11T21:29:09.487+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.487Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Event creating-resource-class.dynamodb.ServiceResource: calling handler <function lazy_call.<locals>._handler at 0x7fa39bd7aca0>
2023-01-11T21:29:09.546+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.546Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Loading dynamodb:Table
2023-01-11T21:29:09.547+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.547Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Event creating-resource-class.dynamodb.Table: calling handler <function lazy_call.<locals>._handler at 0x7fa39bd7ad30>
2023-01-11T21:29:09.584+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.584Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Event creating-resource-class.dynamodb.Table: calling handler <function lazy_call.<locals>._handler at 0x7fa39bd7aca0>
2023-01-11T21:29:09.584+05:00
dynamodb.Table(name='Votes')
2023-01-11T21:29:09.584+05:00
[INFO] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.584Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd event
2023-01-11T21:29:09.584+05:00
[INFO] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.584Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd {'version': '2.0', 'routeKey': 'GET /results', 'rawPath': '/results', 'rawQueryString': '', 'headers': {'accept': 'application/json','user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36', 'x-amzn-trace-id': 'Root=1-63bee3d4-679c4d201abf991d1f331f33', 'x-forwarded-for': '164.40.37.179', 'x-forwarded-port': '443', 'x-forwarded-proto': 'https'}, 'requestContext': {'accountId': '025416187662', 'apiId': '5y7dfynd34', 'domainName': '5y7dfynd34.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com', 'domainPrefix': '5y7dfynd34', 'http': {'method': 'GET', 'path': '/results', 'protocol': 'HTTP/1.1', 'sourceIp': '164.40.37.179', 'userAgent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}, 'requestId': 'eliJRin9oAMEc9Q=', 'routeKey': 'GET /results', 'stage': '$default', 'time': '11/Jan/2023:16:29:08 +0000', 'timeEpoch': 1673454548760}, 'isBase64Encoded': False}
2023-01-11T21:29:09.584+05:00
<class 'boto3.resources.factory.dynamodb.Table'>
2023-01-11T21:29:09.585+05:00 
[INFO] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.584Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd dynamodb.Table(name='Votes')
2023-01-11T21:29:09.585+05:00 
[INFO] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.585Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd <class 'boto3.resources.factory.dynamodb.Table'>
2023-01-11T21:29:09.585+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.585Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Calling dynamodb:get_item with {'TableName': 'Votes', 'Key': {'voter': {'S': 'count'}}}
2023-01-11T21:29:09.585+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.585Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Event provide-client-params.dynamodb.GetItem: calling handler <function  _dynamodb_params at 0x7fa39b870ca0>
2023-01-11T21:29:09.585+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.585Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Event before-parameter-build.dynamodb.GetItem: calling handler <bound method TransformationInjector.inject_condition_expressions of <boto3.dynamodb.transform.TransformationInjector object at 0x7fa39b852730>>
2023-01-11T21:29:09.585+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.585Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Event before-parameter-build.dynamodb.GetItem: calling handler <bound method TransformationInjector.inject_attribute_value_input of <boto3.dynamodb.transform.TransformationInjector object at 0x7fa39b852730>>
2023-01-11T21:29:09.585+05:00 
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.585Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Event before-parameter-build.dynamodb.GetItem: calling handler <function generate_idempotent_uuid at 0x7fa39be0d3a0>
2023-01-11T21:29:09.585+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.585Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Event before-parameter-build.dynamodb.GetItem: calling handler <function block_endpoint_discovery_required_operations at 0x7fa39be32d30>
2023-01-11T21:29:09.586+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.586Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Event before-call.dynamodb.GetItem: calling handler <function inject_api_version_header_if_needed at 0x7fa39be11c10>
2023-01-11T21:29:09.586+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.586Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Making request for OperationModel(name=GetItem) with params: {'url_path': '/', 'query_string': '', 'method': 'POST', 'headers': {'X-Amz-Target': 'DynamoDB_20120810.GetItem', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.0', 'User-Agent': 'Boto3/1.20.32 Python/3.9.13 Linux/4.14.255-296-236.539.amzn2.x86_64 exec-env/AWS_Lambda_python3.9 Botocore/1.23.32 Resource'}, 'body': b'{"TableName": "Votes", "Key": {"voter": {"M": {"S": {"S": "count"}}}}}', 'url': 'https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/', 'context': {'client_region': 'us-east-1', 'client_config': <botocore.config.Config object at 0x7fa39b897c40>, 'has_streaming_input': False, 'auth_type': None}}
2023-01-11T21:29:09.586+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.586Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Event request-created.dynamodb.GetItem: calling handler <bound method RequestSigner.handler of <botocore.signers.RequestSigner object at 0x7fa39b897a90>>
2023-01-11T21:29:09.586+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.586Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Event choose-signer.dynamodb.GetItem: calling handler <function set_operation_specific_signer at 0x7fa39be0d280>
2023-01-11T21:29:09.587+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.587Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Calculating signature using v4 auth.
2023-01-11T21:29:09.587+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.587Z    55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd    CanonicalRequest:
POST
/
content-type:application/x-amz-json-1.0
host:dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
x-amz-date:20230111T162909Z
x-amz-security- x-amz-target:DynamoDB_20120810.GetItem
content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token;x-amz-target
6dd016d6033694be300988a73dded6cba15ade0cf920e8bafb56369e3719c397
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.587Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd CanonicalRequest: POST / content-type:application/x-amz-json-1.0 host:dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com x-amz-date:20230111T162909Z x-amz-target:DynamoDB_20120810.GetItem content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token;x-amz-target 6dd016d6033694be300988a73dded6cba15ade0cf920e8bafb56369e3719c397
2023-01-11T21:29:09.587+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.587Z    55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd    StringToSign:
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20230111T162909Z
20230111/us-east-1/dynamodb/aws4_request
33bbba9cdeb906cc5b3ddc600b02d47f0a73e019d5f3efa0627ea82e05e86eee
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.587Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd StringToSign: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 20230111T162909Z 20230111/us-east-1/dynamodb/aws4_request 33bbba9cdeb906cc5b3ddc600b02d47f0a73e019d5f3efa0627ea82e05e86eee
2023-01-11T21:29:09.587+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.587Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Signature: f36e8c5a9c7d47f1ef41c1ecce566a988f7243f8f95bf7f7c43b951a87e488eb
2023-01-11T21:29:09.644+05:00 
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.643Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Sending http request: <AWSPreparedRequest stream_output=False, method=POST, url=https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/, headers={'X-Amz-Target': b'DynamoDB_20120810.GetItem', 'Content-Type': b'application/x-amz-json-1.0', 'User-Agent': b'Boto3/1.20.32 Python/3.9.13 Linux/4.14.255-296-236.539.amzn2.x86_64 exec-env/AWS_Lambda_python3.9 Botocore/1.23.32 Resource', 'X-Amz-Date': b'20230111T162909Z', 'Authorization': b'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=ASIAQL2XMH4HN6PEJXPA/20230111/us-east-1/dynamodb/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token;x-amz-target, Signature=f36e8c5a9c7d47f1ef41c1ecce566a988f7243f8f95bf7f7c43b951a87e488eb', 'Content-Length': '70'}>
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.644Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Certificate path: /var/runtime/botocore/cacert.pem
2023-01-11T21:29:09.644+05:00
[DEBUG] 2023-01-11T16:29:09.644Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Starting new HTTPS connection (1): dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443
2023-01-11T21:29:17.816+05:00
2023-01-11T16:29:17.815Z 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd Task timed out after 9.01 seconds
2023-01-11T21:29:17.816+05:00 
END RequestId: 55a5e428-c8d6-4914-908c-20ccec1153dd
```

Comment: It seems like the function is trying to make a connection to `dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443`. It is stuck there for 8 seconds and your lambda timeout is set to 9 seconds. That's why the code after `table.get_item` is not run.

Comment: @jellycsc, thank you, i tried to use vpc reachability analyzer.. but how to test the lambda2dynamodb connection? in vpc reach analyzer i tried to get ENI of lambda , but what represents dynamodb table?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue is that the `table.get_item(Key={'voter':{'S': 'count'}})` call is raising an exception, but your exception handling code is not catching it. One possible cause for this could be that the `table.get_item` method is returning a botocore.exception.ClientError object, rather than a Python Exception object. You can modify your except block to catch botocore.exception.ClientError and add some log information like request_id and error message in the catch block.
Another way to detect the error is to enable enhanced monitoring for your lambda function, this will give more detailed metrics on the function performance and error.

One thing you could try is to use `sys.exc_info()` to get the current exception inside the catch block, and print out the exception's class and message. That way you can see exactly what type of exception is being raised and what the error message is.

You could also try to call get_item separately in a local environment to see if it raises an exception, this will help you to figure out if the issue is with your code or the IAM policy or resource configurations.